# How to find $\arccos(\cos\frac{15\pi}{11})$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How to find $\arccos(\cos\frac{15\pi}{11})$?

I'm completely lost. $\frac{15\pi}{11}$ isn't on the unit circle so how do I find the cosine of it?

Comment: Do you understand radians? Pi radians are 180 degrees, 2pi radian to a full circle.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I mean that 15pi/11 isn't on the unit circle in the sense that it's not one of the generic ones like pi/3 or 3pi/2. So how do I find the cosine of something that's not one of the generic values on the unit circle?

Comment: Sorry. I understand now. Using a calculator isn't an option I suppose? A large enough well drawn circle will let you interpolate interim values. 1.3636 pi.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is not a finitely expressed radical form (in which complex numbers are not used) for this value.

Answer (score 1):

As $\cos x=\cos A\implies x=2n\pi\pm A$ where $n$ is any integer

The general value of $$\arccos\left(\cos\frac{15\pi}{11}\right)=2n\pi\pm \frac{15\pi}{11}$$

Based on the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) of principal value inverse cosine ratio, $\displaystyle0\le \arccos x\le\pi$

Taking '+'  sign, $\displaystyle0\le 2n\pi+\frac{15\pi}{11}\le\pi\implies 0\le 22n+15\le 11\implies0\le n<0$ which is impossible

Taking '-'  sign, $\displaystyle0\le 2n\pi-\frac{15\pi}{11}\le\pi\implies 0\le 22n-15\le 11\implies 1\le n\le1\implies n=1$

So, the principal value is $\displaystyle 2\pi-\frac{15\pi}{11}=??$

---

Alternatively, as we know $\cos\left(\pi\pm y\right)=-\cos y$

$$\cos\left(\frac{15\pi}{11}\right)=\cos\left(\pi+\frac{4\pi}{11}\right)=-\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{11}\right)=\cos\left(\pi-\frac{4\pi}{11}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{11}\right)$$

Comment: "15pi/11 isn't on the unit circle" - Do you think OP will find 7pi/11 any easier?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, does not matter. I am supplying a generic solution

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't quite understand your solution. I understand radians.

Comment: @Anon, please find the first method

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, would you  mind checking the edited answer?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee - No doubt, your knowledge is far superior to mine. Your answer may be fine, but Op's comment to me implied he wants to solve by hand, using the circle.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, I think is a generic solution. Does the alternative method help ?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee - OP needs to answer for himself. When he said he understood radians but referred back to the circle, I imagine he'd like to view http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/Unit_circle_angles_color.svg and find the solution.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, I think the alternative method shows the same?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee - I appreciate your diligence, but the OP needs to come back. If he clarified before you answered, the responses might have taken a different turn. I'm still guessing at exactly what his goal is. And my last thought is that he's trying to find these results on the circle from my last comment. +1 by the way. I did not DV you.